# Is it possible to detect cats from dogs in image with single layer perceptron?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron

I want to make a simple application that input is an image and output must be 0 if image is dog and 1 if image is cat. Is it possible to detect cats from dogs in image with single layer perceptron?

Comment: I think its best you try it and see if the results are good enough for your requirements

Answer (score 1):

No, that's just not possible.

> Although the [perceptron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) initially seemed promising, it was quickly proved that perceptrons could not be trained to recognise many classes of patterns.

Check the Wikipedia article on the subject.